# Get div from another site using DOMDocument in PHP

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to get a div from my another site. I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('http://lemans.net.pl/wroclaw');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);
$div = $doc->getElementByID('part');
     echo $div->nodeValue;
?>
```

Comment: "It does not work" is not really helping us out. Do you get an error? Is the result not as expected? What's up? ;-)

Comment: The function is `getElementById` (note the lowercase 'd').

Comment: Firebug doesnt do yor job?

Comment: @apomene: How would that help with a PHP script?

Comment: @RocketHazmat he doesnt have to use php...

Comment: @apomene: But he is in the question.

Comment: Well..maybe I have misunderstood the Q

Comment: I'm getting this http://danielkoczula.pl/lemans.php

Comment: @DanielKoczuła: The site you are loading may not be valid HTML.

Comment: What is the return status of `$doc->loadHTML($page);`, TRUE or FALSE?

Comment: @DanielKoczuła I posted an answer you your question and provided a potential solution.  Please review and an up vote and/or accept would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious about DOMDocument so I experimented a bit.  I wrote the following demo program to illustrate a few key concepts that may help you:

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('http://lemans.net.pl/wroclaw');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);

$doc->validateOnParse = true;

$div = $doc->getElementById('part');

echo "<br>------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
echo $tag = $div->hasChildNodes()?" hasChildNodes":" hasNoChildNodes";
echo "<br>------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
echo $div->tagName;
echo "<br>------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
$elements = $div->getElementsByTagName('*');
echo $elements->length;
echo "<br>------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
foreach ($elements as $node) {
  echo $node->tagName . " - href: " . $node->getAttribute('href') . "<br>";
}
echo "<br>------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
echo htmlspecialchars($doc->saveHTML($div));
echo "<br>------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
echo $doc->saveHTML($div);
echo "<br>------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
?>
```

You can try the PHP Fiddle at: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8hf-nrk (Click Run button...)

**Some Explanations and Notes**

(1) When you load the document, you may see a list of warnings, some related to special characters that don't get encoded properly or nested tags that confuse the parser.

(2) The `validateOnParse` option does not seem to make a difference, but I put it in just in case.

(3) Once you get the node from the document, stored in `$div`, you now have a  DOM fragment that you can use.  You can do things like get the `tagName`, see if it `hasChildNodes` and so on.  By the way, `nodeValue` is NULL or empty since there is no content in the div, just child elements.

(4) You can use `getElementsByTagName` to get a list all the child nodes. See the `foreach` loop that lists the tag names and one of the attributes.

(5) If you are trying to echo out the `div` and its child content, use `saveHTML`.
You can see the raw code by passing it through `htmlspecialchars` or you can insert
the div directly into the document flow and display the active links and logo images.

I think this should help you along your way.  Good luck!